# Property of Gamma Function applied to $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{z+n}+\int_1^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\ dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

Show that $zF(z)=F(z+1)$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,-1,\dots\}$. Here is my attempt:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{z}{z+n}+z\int_1^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\ dt
\end{equation}
Let us look at the second expression first:
\begin{equation}
z\int_1^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}=[t^z\cdot e^{-t}]_1^\infty+\int_1^\infty t^ze^{-t}=e^{-1}+\int_1^\infty t^ze^{-t}
\end{equation}
I, however, can't simplify the first expression to equal $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{z+1+n}-e^{-1}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, you get minus $e^{-1}$ after integrating by part, not plus. Second, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{z}{z+n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{z+n-n}{z+n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}\cdot \frac{1}{z+n}$, next make change $n\to n+1$

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach. Let consider the RHS:
$$I: = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{z+1+n}+e^{-1}
=- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\cdot \frac{n}{z+n}+e^{-1} $$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\frac{z}{z+n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} +e^{-1}$$
Applying the Maclaurin series for $e^{-1}$, we obtain:
$$I = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\frac{z}{z+n}+1=z \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\frac{1}{z+n} $$
Since:
$$\int_1^\infty t^{z}e^{-t}\ dt = - t^{z}e^{-t}\Bigg|_1^\infty + z\int_1^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\ dt
$$
$$= e^{-1} + z\int_1^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\ d$$
Hence, adding terms by terms will yield desired equality.